# How to fix "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist"?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a function which get a value from firebase before navigating to another page. Unfortunately I'm getting this error "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist" when the function is called. However, if I Hot reload my app the function is called and the value is there. Do you guys have any idea how can I fix this?

here is the function:

```
  Future<void> getDeliveryPrice(String profileId) async {
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await storeRef.doc(profileId).get();

    final price = doc['delPrice'] as num;

    deliveryPrice = price;
    print(profileId);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And here is where I call the function:

```
  PriceCard(
     buttonText: 'Continuar para a Entrega',
     onPressed: cartManager.isCartValid
         ? () {
            cartManager.getDeliveryPrice(profileId);
            print(profileId);

             Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => AddressScreen(profileId),
             ));
            } : null,
          )
```

Comment: ```doc.data()['delPrice'] as num;```, i dont know if theres a difference here. but i think you should get its .data().. And whats the pakacge version of your cloud_firestore?

Comment: doc is of type `DocumentSnapshot` it has a method `data()` which return a map with the document fields and values

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work. The function works without the ```data()``` but only if I hot reload the app, but when I call it it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the `profileId` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3826). It says that the error is related to recent changes in `DocumentSnapshot`. The data used to be in `doc`, but is now in `doc.data()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer Mickael, I've already tried that, but it doesn't work. The function works without the ```data()``` but only if I hot reload the app, but when I call it it doesn't.

Comment: That's likely because you're not listening on updates. Use either a `Consumer`/`Selector` widget or the `context.watch<T>()` function.